# Grammar checker in VS CODE

Tags: visual-studio-code, text, ide

I need to check the grammar of various docstrings, is there a way to do that directly in Visual Studio Code (or any other editor) without copying and pasting each docstring in a grammar checker like Grammarly?

Comment: I don't use either VS Code (not a Windows user) or Grammarly (the grammar I need to check is not English). LanguageTool works OK for me (in Spanish); it might not be great, but it catches most of my barbarisms. I understand that there is a [third-party tool](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=davidlday.languagetool-linter) which integrates it into VSCode; I know nothing about that extension except that it showed up one day in my inbox. Maybe it can help you. But you should be aware that tool requests are off-topic on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

There is a VSCode [Grammarly](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=znck.grammarly) extension.

At the bottom of the extension settings for Grammarly, under Grammarly>Files: Include you could add Python files to be checked, by adding:

**/*.py

Note, that this would include the whole Python file and not just the docstrings.